# jQuery Object Method Gets Called Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a jQuery method which watches for changes of inputs inside a given form element:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.filter = function(options) {
        console.log('Outside');

        var self = this;
        var settings = $.extend({}, options);        

        this.on('change', ':input', function(e) {
            console.log('Inside');

           $(self).serialize(); // Here is the problem

        });

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#filter-form').filter();
```

When I use `$(self).serialize();`, the function being called again. I expect that the 'Outside' part only runs once on initialization and not every time the input of the form changes.

I do not understand what is happening here. I'd appreciate if someone could explain to me why this is happening!

Comment: The problem is because jQuery already has a `filter()` method and your code is causing confusion. Change the name of your function and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3ba2L7ky/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are redefining jQuery's `filter` method, which it internally uses in its `serialize` method. If you change the name, it will work. The definition of `serialize` is shown below:

```
jQuery.fn.extend( {
    serialize: function() {
        return jQuery.param( this.serializeArray() );
    },
    serializeArray: function() {
        return this.map( function() {

            // Can add propHook for "elements" to filter or add form elements
            var elements = jQuery.prop( this, "elements" );
            return elements ? jQuery.makeArray( elements ) : this;
        } )
        .filter( function() {
            var type = this.type;

            // Use .is( ":disabled" ) so that fieldset[disabled] works
            return this.name && !jQuery( this ).is( ":disabled" ) &&
                rsubmittable.test( this.nodeName ) && !rsubmitterTypes.test( type ) &&
                ( this.checked || !rcheckableType.test( type ) );
        } )
        .map( function( _i, elem ) {
            var val = jQuery( this ).val();

            if ( val == null ) {
                return null;
            }

            if ( Array.isArray( val ) ) {
                return jQuery.map( val, function( val ) {
                    return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
                } );
            }

            return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
        } ).get();
    }
} );
```

Working Example:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn._filter = function(options) {
    console.log('Outside');

    var self = this;
    var settings = $.extend({}, options);

    this.on('change', ':input', function(e) {
      console.log('Inside');

      $(self).serialize();

    });

    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);

$('#filter-form')._filter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="filter-form">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @pete No problem.